# UIImagePickerController takePicture not responding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I init the UIImagePickerController:

```
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

and then use this method `[imagePicker takePicture];`

and I not get any call to the delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Any idea why?

Comment: whether it gets called in simulator ?

Comment: change the source type to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary and check it in simulator..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention if you're actually presenting the image picker controller to the user by calling `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` (or the older `presentViewController:animated:`).

Apple's docs don't explicitly say so, but I'm pretty sure the image picker controller needs to be shown on screen in order for `-takePicture` to work, otherwise you would be able to take pictures without the user knowing.

Comment: and if i want to take picture without the user will know it for security problems?

Answer (score 1):

To use an image picker controller, you must provide a delegate that conforms to the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol.

if it does, verify that the device is capable of picking content from the desired source. Do this calling the isSourceTypeAvailable: class method, providing a constant from the “UIImagePickerControllerSourceType” enum.

Also check 'self' hasn't been released.

Comment: Trisha has a good point, the delegates won't fire in the Simulator. The isSourceTypeAvailable method would have accounted for this obviously.