# UIImagePickerController takePicture

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to use `UIImagePickerController` takePicture method.
the problem his that the UIImagePickerController is not show in the screen and the user cannot press the Use button to accept the img.
Is there is any way to skip this screen and go straight to :

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

for saving the image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController takePicture not responding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068436/uiimagepickercontroller-takepicture-not-responding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I have found to do this is to use a custom overlay for UIImagePickerController. You can do that with code akin to that below:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

//create custom overlay and allocate it as "customOverlayView"
picker.cameraOverlayView = customOverlayView;

//do any other setup desired for picker

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
[picker release];
```

Now once the takePicture method is called, the delegate didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: will be called immediately like you desire.